# Self hosting two wcf interfaces (one of them is duplex)

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex

I need to build a service that serves two interfaces. One interface uses basicHttpBinding, and the other should be netTcpBinding. The other one should also support duplex communication.

basicHttp interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "accesspointService")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IVERAAccessPoint
{
    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(MyClass obj);
}
```

Implementation:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(Name = "accesspointService", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2009/02/ws-tra")]
public class VERAAccessPoint : IVERAAccessPoint
{
    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(MyClass obj)
    {
        //something
        return composite;
    }
}
```

duplex netTcpContract:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientCallback))]
public interface IVERAAPCS
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void Subscribe(ClientInfo info);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void Unsubscribe(ClientInfo info);

}

public interface IClientCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void PushDocument(XDocument doc);
}

[DataContract]
public class ClientInfo
{
    public string id;

}
```

And implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class VERAAPCS : IVERAAPCS
{
    public void Subscribe(ClientInfo info)
    {
        //something
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(ClientInfo info)
    {
        //Something
    }
}
```

I tried to self host both interfaces and this is the best i could do:

```
Uri baseAddress1 = new Uri("http://localhost:6544/hello");
//host the first interface
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(VERAAccessPoint.VERAAccessPoint), baseAddress))
{

    // Enable metadata publishing.
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    host.Open();
    //Host the second (duplex interface)
    using (ServiceHost host2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(VERAAccessPoint.VERAAPCS)))
    {
        host2.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(VERAAccessPoint.IVERAAPCS), new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:6543/hello2");
        host2.Open();
        Console.ReadLine();
        host2.Close();
    }
    host.Close();
}
```

Now for the consuming part:
    //Consuming the first interface (this works so i removed it form the question)
    //Consuming the second interface:

```
var myBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:6543/hello2");
var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<VERAAccessPoint.IVERAAPCS>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

VERAAccessPoint.IVERAAPCS client = null;

client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

This produces the following error:

> ChannelFactory does not support the contract IVERAAPCS as it defines a callback contract with one or more operations.  Please consider using DuplexChannelFactory instead of ChannelFactory.

But I just can't seem to find a way to use the duplexChannelFactory.
So my question is basically how do you consume a duplex netTcpBinding service tat is self hosted?

Sorry for the long question, but I wanted to provide as much information as I could. Thanks

Comment: What did you try on your way to "can't seem to find a way"? There is an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576164.aspx) that seems very straightforward. Maybe you could post an actual problem you have while trying to use it?

Comment: why do you have your `ServiceHost` objects in a `using` block?  As soon as you exit the `using` block, the host will close, will it not?

Comment: @Tim Sorry, there is a Console.ReadLine() inthe using block. It got lost when I was shortening the code to post it here.

Comment: @nvoigt I'll check that link of your and see if it is similar to what i have tried so far, or will it solve my problem. I will come to edit the question after that. Thanks

Comment: @nvoigt My main problem with the solution on your link and every other solution is that every one of those solutions imply the use of a "Client" class (Named "ChatApp" in your solution or "TemperatureClient" in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34460/WCF-Duplex-Reentrant-Services) solution. However this class is usually generated by adding a service reference which I can't do because of the way that i hosted the service (presumably issues with a mex endpoint). Should I post a question about my problems in adding a service reference? Thanks for your time and excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @Solver - All you need for `ChannelFactory` or `DuplexChannelFactory` is the interface of the service, you don't need to add a service reference.  The simplest way to do this is to move your two interfaces into a separate assembly (a class library), and then your self-hosting application can reference that assembly and your client(s) can also reference that assembly. Let me know if you would like me to post an example - it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Tim I managed to add a service reference by messing with the configuration. You could post an example in an answer so I can try both solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Per your request in the comments, here's an example.

Place all of your interfaces in a separate assembly.  For purposes of this example, let's name it ServiceContracts and use the namespace `VERAAccessPoint.ServiceContracts`.

Inside this assembly (which you'll want to create as a class library - DLL), you place `IVERAAccessPoint`, `IVERAAPCS`, `IClientCallback` and the data contract `ClientInfo`.

Next, add add a reference to the ServiceContracts assembly in your self-hosted application and a `using` directive:

`using VerAAccessPoint.ServiceContracts;`

That way you can implement the contract interfaces and host the services.

Finally, in your client application add the reference to the assembly and the `using` directive, and then you can do the following:

```
IVERAAPCS client = null;
var myBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:6543/hello2");
var myDuplexChannelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IVERAAPCS>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

client = myDuplexChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

You could do something similar with `ChannelFactory<T>` using `IVERAAccessPoint` as well.

I have used `ChannelFactory<T>` a lot, but never the `DuplexChannelFactory<T>`, but this should give you another option to explore.